# Tkinter: infinite loop in login system

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

```
def login():
    username_login = username_entry.get()
    password_login = password_entry.get()
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('login_dabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM logindata')
    records = c.fetchall()
    
    conn.commit()
    conn.close  
    for (a,b) in records:
        if username_login==a:
            if password_login==b:
                loginwindow = Tk()
                success_label = Label(loginwindow,text="Sucessfully logged in") 
                success_label.grid(row=0,column=0)

        if username_login=='':

            if password_login=='':
                messagebox.showinfo("Empty","Required fields are empty")
        else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error","Incorrect Credentials")
```

so this version of the function is where is tried to restrict the user from clicking on login without entering any details but when I click on login without any credentials a lot of windows pop and the user is able to login successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors that could be causing you problems, this is how I would go about doing this. By separating the actual logic for validating the login credentials to its own function, our `login` function can focus on interacting with the GUI elements.

```py
def validate_credentials(username, password):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('login_dabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM logindata WHERE username=?', (username_login,))  # so-called "prepared statement"
    record = c.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    if record:
        _, correct_password = record
        if password==correct_password:
            return True
    return False

def login():
    username_login = username_entry.get()
    password_login = password_entry.get()
    
    if validate_credentials(username_login, password_login):
        loginwindow = Tk()
        success_label = Label(loginwindow,text="Sucessfully logged in") 
        success_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Invalid Credentials")
```

It should be noted that this is probably not a "production-ready" manner by which to provide user authentication, but for a simple learning example it will suffice.

Comment: Yes, this was purely written to learn tkinter integrated with sqlite3.

Comment: I believe the big issue was that you were not actually calling the `conn.close()` function, as you were missing your parenthesis. This could have caused the connection to hang.